# Two routers off one internet line for two different networks

Tags: networking

Ok here is my situation. My sisters family moved in with us and there kind of stubborn with the internet. They want to use their router for their own network. The way I have it setup is we have our service provider modem going to our router witch creates our network and then their router is plugged into our router for their own network in their room. All they use it for is their PlayStation and phones. ( total waste if you ask me ) any time I do something with our router it effects theirs.
 Here is my question. Is it possible to go from the ISP modem to both routers so nether of them are connected to each other. I tried doing a switch from the modem and then to both routers but only one router gets internet access. Iv heard of a network splitter. From one network cable/port to two cables/ports. Would this work or am I trying to do the impossible here? 
Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: what do you mean "I do something with my router?"

Comment: Like modifying settings like port forwarding and restarting the router. Witch then kills their internet for a couple of minutes witch isn't bad but to them it's the end of the world

Comment: How many ports does your modem have? Does your modem have something called bridging? Try turning that off (a bit slower internet, but perhaps more compatible). Also don't forget that each router has to work in a different subnet so that they don't conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP allows you multiple IP addresses then you can use a switch and configure each router to use one of them.  Other then that you need some kind of Network Address Translation, NAT, which is what a router does - that's why plugging their router into yours works.  If your ISP will give you two IPs for your one modem then you can do it.  Other than that you need a NAT somewhere which means plugging one router into the other.  Each layer of NAT does add some latency to the connection however so if you don't require gaming pings then you might want to plug their router into the modem and yours into theirs.

Comment: Also, if your modem has routing functions built into it (either it doesn't or you have them turned off as plugging both routers into a switch connected to the modem didn't work) then in the modem's settings look for "residential gateway function" or similar and turn that off.  Then your modem/router becomes a simple dumb modem which if you have your own - better - router is what you want.

Comment: Option B: Tell them to get their own internet service.

Comment: Ok. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I wish they would but not very likely to happen

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I found a temporary fix and now have a new question related to this issue if any one is able to help.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1274680/seporating-two-networks-with-dmz