# separating two networks with DMZ?

Tags: networking, nat, subnet, dmz

I am a college student wanting to get into server and networking but I have an issue I need help with at home. I asked a question about a year ago about creating two separate networks with the same internet connection. I had a temporary fix until I ran into a problem.

**Current situation:**

My sister's family lives with us and they are using their own router for their own network. It is currently connected to my router (Asus RT-AC68R).

Any time I make changes to my router settings that require a restart it effects their internet.

I do gaming and currently have a 24/7 file server that I have setup on my network with VPN server on my router to access the server from the internet. I use to have three routers set up to separate the networks,

My router, and my sister's router were connected to the main router that was connected to the internet. My problem is my VPN server on my router would not work I could not connect to the VPN server from over the internet to access my file server on my network.

I changed it back so my router is the main router and my sisters is connected to mine. I am now able to use my VPN and file server over the internet but brings me back to the original issue of their network being affected by my settings.

**Question:**

Would it work or be a bad idea to do the three router setup again but put my router in the DMZ of the first router. This would separate mine and my sister family's networks while still putting my router out on the internet as if it was the main router thus enabling me to connect to the VPN server and access my file server or would it not work like this or be a bad idea?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a perfectly reasonable solution. Or, upgrade your internet service to have at least two static IP addresses and plug both routers in to your ISP Modem and assign a different public IP to each router. Now both will be connected “directly” to the internet and completely independent of each other. You can also port forward or enable IPSec pass through instead of using a DMZ.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your input. I wish I could pay for two Public IP's but don't want to spend more right now on internet haha.

Comment: The problem is that you are doing double-NAT and the VPN will be opening a port on *your* router, probably via UPnP, but cannot discover the router beyond it to do the same there. In theory putting your router in the dmz would make it publicly accessible and any requests from the internet should route to it by default. Why do you need to be constantly restarting your own router?

Comment: I'm not constantly restarting it. but it happens enough that it causes issues for their network. I like to tinker and fidle with things to learn more about networks and so every now and then I will be changing something that may be related to my server or address routing that usually requires a restart. also currently I don't have any internet filters or related because they were complaining about services they used being blocked. so splitting our networks will enable me to add those filters back on to my network.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went to the store and bought a decent mid grade router with dmz. Set that up as my main router and then connected my router and my sisters router two the main router. I then used the main router to dmz my router and tested my vpn and it works. thanks.